# How to exclude spring boot application beans from the test App context?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, javabeans, spock

I am currently defining my Base specification as below:

```
@Configuration
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:test-config-context.xml" )
class SpringSharedSpecification extends Specification
```

This also end up in processing my parent application-context.xml

I am using active profile option to not to load the main beans and execute with test-config
I used below to skip application-context beans but doesn't feel it is the best way to do it. Can anyone suggest better way of skipping application-context.xml?

```
<beans profile="!test">
```

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use annotation on your bean class:

```
@Component
@Profile("!test")
class MyProductionBean {
}
```

Comment: Glad for you. Could you please mark this answer as 'accepted' (by pressing green mark sign)